# How long does the game last?

Tags: championship-manager-2

In Championship Manager 2, how long does the game last?

I have tried hunting around for the answer but the [closest I could get](http://community.sigames.com/showthread.php/360394-How-long-does-the-game-last) was speculation that either the game automatically retired you (possibly when you were 75) or the game just went on forever.

The odd thing is, the game doesn't store your age (or any manager's age).  However, there is a value for `number of years in the game` and computer managers will eventually retire.  Additionally, you could bypass such a restriction by just adding a new manager when your current manager retires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Championship Manager 97/98 (the latest version of Championship Manager 2) the game lasts **29 full seasons**.

On the final day of season 29 the menu will appear as follows:

[image: Final day of the season]

You can press `Done` to begin processing the end of season, but following the announcement of the end of season awards you will see this message:

[image: End of season]

Note, the message quotes "around 30 seasons" but it is exactly 29 complete seasons.